# Views exposed filter by node title

Tags: views

I want create a related content block by searching in node title,for doing this i created a views and add a views search filter,my problem is i dont know how auto set node title as search value.
there is any token for filter value ? like `[node:title]` when user visit a node it put node,title in search value.

Comment: you have to alter the form using form alter and get the values from node_load function & put the default value of the text field , the node title

Comment: if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'view_name' && $form_state['view']->current_display == 'display') {$form['field_name']['#default_value'] = $node->title;

Comment: unfortunately , i am not good in coding , can you explain more ?

Comment: in you custom module put this code 
function saletraderent_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'view_name' && $form_state['view']->current_display == 'display') {
//print_r($form);exit;
$form['field_name']['#default_value'] = $node->title;
}
}
where view name you can find by exporting you view and display in advance section machine name something like page and field name by print_r($form);exit;